# Как спарсить и вывести все названия секций (блоков) со статьи Википедии?

Tags: python, wikipedia

Программирую на `python`. Выбрал на данный момент библиотеку `wikipedia`, всё было хорошо, но столкнулся с проблемой парсинга названий секций. Требовалось, чтобы программа нашла все названия блоков данной статьи и вывела их через `print`. Казалось задачей легкой, но вот в данной библиотеке ничего такого не нашел. Например, в [https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neural_networkесть](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neural_network%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C) 10 разделов: Overview, History, Artifical intelligence, Applications, Neuroscience и т.д. Мне нужны названия этих разделов. Могли бы предложить какие библиотеки могут справиться с такой задачей?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашёл библиотеку wikipediaAPI, просмотрел документацию и решил таким образом:

```
import wikipediaapi

wiki_wiki = wikipediaapi.Wikipedia('en')
page_py = wiki_wiki.page('Neural_network')

def print_sections(sections):
        for s in sections:
                print("%s" % (s.title))
                

print_sections(page_py.sections)
```

Вывод:

```
History
Artificial intelligence
Applications
Neuroscience
Criticism
Recent improvements
See also
References
External links
```

Answer (score 0):

> программа нашла все названия блоков данной статьи

https://waksoft.susu.ru/2021/04/06/kak-s-pomoshhyu-python-izvlech-dannye-iz-vikipedii/

```
import wikipedia

result = wikipedia.search("Neural networks")
# получить страницу: Neural network
page = wikipedia.page(result[0])

# получение категорий страницы
categories = page.categories
```

Comment: Данный способ выводит не то, что нужно. Мне нужны названия разделов данной статьи. Например, в https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neural_network есть 10 разделов: Overview, History, Artifical intelligence, Applications, Neuroscience и т.д. Мне нужны названия этих разделов